# Is it possible to Marshal an unmanaged array of struct without a loop?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm getting binary data from a serial communication that I need to marshal into C# managed structures. All working fine.

One of the responses is an array of structs, which I'm marshalling as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = /* binary data from serial port */
int sizeOfElement = Marshal.SizeOf(element);
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeOfElement);
int numElements = buffer.Length / sizeOfElement;
TItem[] array = new TItem[numElements]; //TItem is a generic type

for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
{
    int offset = (sizeOfElement * i);
    Marshal.Copy(this.Content, offset, ptr, sizeOfElement);
    array[i] = (TItem)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TItem));
    Marshal.DestroyStructure(ptr, typeof(TItem));
}

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Is it possible to accomplish this without the loop? I've looked around in MSDN and here in SO but haven't found anything that could replace the call to `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` with one that takes the whole buffer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Downvoter looking forward to your feedback as to how specifically the question can be improved

Comment: It can be improved.  Avoid the awkward copying by pinning the array with GCHandle, use its AddrOfPinnedObject() to get the IntPtr.  If you can live with unsafe then use the `fixed` keyword to get a byte*, cast to IntPtr. If you absolutely want to get rid of the loop then UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadArray() gets that job done.  Or just don't worry about it, serial ports are slow.